# How to handle duplicate value Exception in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I have a `Users` model class which has `UserID` as primary key. I want to handle the exception if duplicate value for `UserID` (primary key) is inserted and display a proper message to the user.

I tried to handle exception by using

```
try 
{
    db.SaveChanges();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var sqlException = ex.InnerException as SqlException;

    if (sqlException.Number == 2627 || sqlException.Number == 2601 ) 
        MessageBox.Show("User already exists");
}
```

but this didn't work as VS 2015 throws the null exception error.

Here is my `Users` model class

```
class Users
{
        [Key]
        [MaxLength(10), MinLength(5)]
        public string userID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string password { get; set; }

        public bool isAdmin { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you check db for that id? It's not so expensive check.

Comment: `I tried to handle exception by using` Did it work?

Comment: `Why don't you check db for that id? It's not so expensive check.` @CanFil that would _reduce_ the risk but not eliminate it entirely - given this is maybe a race condition.

Comment: Try using Identity column for primary key (int), and by default it won't insert any duplicates, you can handle what duplicates should not be inserted using insertion code logic rather than writing code in catch block

Comment: IDENTITY doesn't solve the issue @aelagawy. Ultimately, the DB needs to have some form of UNIQUE constraint / index to protect against duplicate email addresses etc. `using insertion code logic` What kind of logic do you envisage? The way the OP has done it is the way I'd do it. INSERT, and if it fails with a specific exception - must be a duplicate.

Comment: The implication is that the inner exception (if any) is not a SqlException. What exactly is the Exception, and what are the inner exceptions?

Comment: First of all I'm not a big fan of IDENTITY column, However as I understood from the example to keep the model status valid by using identity column and implement the extra username or identical value, but may be I got him/her wrong
Thanks anyway for clarification. @mjwills

Answer (score 3):

The null reference exception is raised because the first inner exception is not a `SqlException`. What you get is a `DbUpdateException`, its inner exception is an `UpdateException` and this exception's inner exception is a `SqlException`.

You have to traverse the inner exceptions until you find the `SqlException`, for which you can use this method:

```cs
public TException GetInnerException<TException>(Exception exception)
    where TException : Exception
{
    Exception innerException = exception;
    while (innerException != null) 
    {
        if (innerException is TException result)
        {
            return result;
        }
        innerException = innerException.InnerException;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Which turns your code into:

```cs
catch (DbUpdateException ex) // catch DbUpdateException explicitly
{
    var sqlException = GetInnerException<SqlException>(ex);

    if (sqlException != null 
        && (sqlException.Number == 2627 || sqlException.Number == 2601) )
    {
        MessageBox.Show("User already exists");
    }
}
```